# Authentication with LocomotiveCMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, locomotivecms

I am pretty new to RoR development and newer to LocomotiveCMS...that said, I am trying to build a relatively simple site with LocomotiveCMS.  Ideally, I would like to restrict the entire site from anonymous users, and then extend the roles as read-only, contribute, admin, etc.  I see that Locomotive uses devise for authentication for /admin.  Is there a way to restrict access to only authenticated users?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to make every page unpublished. Users would then have to be logged into the CMS to be able to see any of the pages.

Answer (score 0):

This [PR](https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine/pull/153) adds switch in page settings for restriction of anonymous users.